# Why __loader__.load_module failed to import module the first time and succeeded the second time

Tags: python, module, loader, python-3.10

[image]

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __loader__.load_module("subprocess").run(["whoami"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 774, in create_module
ImportError: 'subprocess' is not a built-in module
>>> __loader__.load_module("subprocess").run(["whoami"])
root
CompletedProcess(args=['whoami'], returncode=0)
>>>
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening. And if I want to write codes in PyCharm, how can I user **load**.load_module because it will always fail

Comment: Please post as text not screenshot.